# Time not utc linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

## How can I get my local time by pulling information from the Internet without using utc time?

When I run the command below it will always return the time in utc format...

```
curl -I ' https://google.com/ ' 2>/dev/null | grep -i '^date:' | sed 's/^[Dd]ate: //g'
```

I would just like it to show the result in my local time and not with utc.

Comment: well, you can't tell google what to return - and I believe headers always use GMT/UTC anyway ... are you perhaps asking how to convert UTC time string into your local time?

Comment: that's right I need it to convert to my local time through the result obtained by the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will show that date in local time, using `date --date=STRING`

```
date --date="$(curl -I 'https://google.com/' 2>/dev/null | grep -i '^date:' | sed -e 's/^date: //')"
```

Comment: why are you extracting the year and thinking it's the hour? you save the year to `/root/hora.txt`  - you read `/root/hour.txt` (what created that?) into `hour2`, you set the time to `$time2UTC` (not defined) ...  you `echo $hour` (not defined) - that whole script is hot garbage

Comment: my code extracts full date and time ... yours, with the `cut` extracts year (at least on my system)

Comment: tell me, exactly what is the result of MY code on your system? note, your code does `date +%T%Z -s "$hourUTC"` ... and `$hourUTC` is what? and why are you setting the system clock to whatever that is?

Comment: again, this is all beyond the original question asked - you asked, I answered ... if you're then going to do bizarre things with the result that mainly make no sense, that doesn't mean this answer is wrong ... it answers exactly what you asked

Comment: I understand, again thanks for your help friend.